# How to determine from where came exception?

Tags: .net, exception

Here is the code structre:

```
 try
    {
       --outter code block;

       try
         { 
            --inner code block;
         }

        catch(Exeption ex)
        {
          throw new Exception() 
          --inner catch block
        }
    }
    catch(Exeption ex) 
    {
       --outter catch block
    }
```

How can I determine in outter catch block if exception generated in **outter code block**  or throwed in inner catch block?

Comment: Do you really have code with `catch(Exeption ex)` as the exception handlers? You shouldn't do that. It's as bad as using `goto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you handle this is the inner code block should be including the execption in its `innerException` parameter if you plan on throwing a new exception or just using `throw;` to let the exception bubble up.

```
try
{
   //outter code block;

   try
     { 
        //inner code block;
     }

    catch(Exeption ex)
    {
      throw new MySpecialException("Some Extra Information", ex);
      // or
      throw;
    }
}
catch(Exeption ex) 
{
   //ex.InnerException contains the "ex" from up above if you used MySpecialException
   // or ex will be the same exception with the same stack trace if you used throw;
}
```

Note, it is considered extremely bad practice to do `throw new Exception` you should always be throwing some more derived exception or [your own user exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx) and that exception you throw should add some new piece of information. If you don't need to create a new exception to add more information just use the `throw;`

Answer (score 1):

Throw exceptions of different types or pass different string arguments to the constructor.

Comment: Indeed, with appropriate, different types, one wouldn't need such code in the catch block.

Comment: You mean to check in outer catch block if the 'ex.message' have string?